# How do I compare two MySQL tables and then update one of them

Tags: mysql

I have two tables called it_systems and departments. The it_systems table contains all the department names but I want to add in all their ID's so I can remove the deprtmentNames column. so I need to compare the name with the name in the department table and then insert the departments.id into the it_systems.departmentid but seems to be falling flat as MySQL is not that great.
This is how far I have got

```
UPDATE 
it_system_additional INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT departmentName
    FROM it_system_additional
) departments ON departments.DepartmentName = it_system_additional.departmentName
SET it_system_additional.departmentid = departments.departmentId
```

but I keep getting this error 
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'departments.departmentId' in 'field list'
even though I know that column does exist.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User below query to achieve this:

```
UPDATE it_system_additional AS i
INNER JOIN departments AS d ON i.DepartmentName = d.departmentName
SET i.departmentid = d.departmentId
```

Comment: Perfect. So simple. Thank you so so much.